# How to set a Flink Operator acting on many streams

Tags: apache-flink, apache-storm, flink-streaming

I am looking into using Flink for streaming Engine. I am coming from apache-storm and As I understand storm's Bolt is similar to Flink's task/operator. In storm one can have

```
 builder.setBolt("TEST", new TestBolt(),5)
        .fieldsGrouping("Source1", "ID1")
        .fieldsGrouping("Source2","ID2)
        .fieldsGrouping("Source3","ID1")
        .allGrouping("Source4");
```

How can I achieve something similar with Flink. Basically I want my test Bolt to have state from Source2, source3, source4 and do some computation when data from source 1 comes.

Answer (score 1):

Your options for combining streams in Flink include `union` (for merging n streams of the same type), `connect` for jointly processing two streams of any type with a CoFlatMap or CoProcessFunction, and `broadcast`.

In some cases it's preferable to build a sort of binary tree,  connecting, for example, streams 1 and 2 to form stream 12, and separately, streams 3 and 4 to create stream 34, and then connect stream12 with stream 34.

The alternative is to create some sort of union type that can hold an object from any of the streams, and then use union to merge the streams. Flink includes an `Either` type that can be helpful in these situations.

Comment: Thanks @David Anderson , The types from Source1-4 are all different. How do I take union of say Source1,2,3 and connect with Source4 ?